# Using missing_kwds with geopandas changes the shape of the displayed map

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I'm using Geopandas (0.11.1) to plot data on maps. I'm facing an issue with `missing_kwds`. As some of my values are undefined, I want them to be colored in a specific way. I do that using the `missing_kwds` option of the `plot` method.
However, when using it, the shape of the map slightly changes, which is disgraceful when switching quickly from one to the other.

Here is an example.

A map without using `missing_kwds` :

```py
import geopandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
df.plot()
plt.savefig('world1.png')
```

A map using `missing_kwds` :

```py
import geopandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
df = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
df.loc[df.name=="China", 'pop_est'] = np.nan
df.plot(column="pop_est", missing_kwds=dict(color="lightgray"))
plt.savefig('world2.png')
```

Those are the two resulting maps.

world1.png:

[image: world1.png]

world2.png:

[image: world2.png]

In case the difference isn't clear, here is a GIF that illustrates the shape changes.

[image: world.gif]

Does anyone have an idea how I could solve this issue?

Comment: You must use `missing_kwds=dict(color=None, aspect='equal')` to get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually working on this example, but it doesn't work anymore when focusing on one region of the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add plt.gca().set_aspect('equal') after df.plot().

Comment: Great, thanks! Originally I tried setting the `aspect` parameter of the Geopandas `plot` method, but it didn't change anything. Do you know why?